# `npm install` error when installing in docker container permissions error

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, permissions, npm-install

I've got a weird error that happens on my new laptop but not on my old one (new: M1 ARM Mac, old: Intel Mac).

I mount my code as a volume in docker-compose and would bring the container up and just `npm install` and everything would install correctly. node_modules would get created in the volume and I could run. On the new Mac, it throws a permissions error.

**Docker-compose volume mount:**

```
volumes:
- ./:/app/
```

What's weird about these is that I can go in to the directories that it's complaining about, while in the docker container, and create/view files.

- Node Version: 10.24.0
- NPM Version: 5.8.0

**First Error:**

```
glob error { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/app/node_modules/signal-exit']node_modules/shallowequal
  errno: -1,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/app/node_modules/signal-exit' }
```

**Second Error**

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/app/node_modules/set-value/package.json.1296712643'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/app/node_modules/set-value/package.json.1296712643']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/app/node_modules/set-value/package.json.1296712643'
npm ERR!      errno: -1,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!      path: '/app/node_modules/set-value/package.json.1296712643' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open \'/app/node_modules/set-value/package.json.1296712643\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/app/node_modules/set-value/package.json.1296712643',
npm ERR!   parent: 'capella' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
```

Any suggestions on what to do next would be appreciated.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to delete that `volumes:` block.  Then when your Dockerfile executes the `RUN npm install` line, its within the isolated container filesystem and you don't need to worry about trying to figure out how to manage the host filesystem permissions.

Comment: The volumes block contains my entire application with the node_modules nested inside. I copied the package.json into a folder outside of the volume and tried `npm install` and it worked, so something is wrong with the volume, I just don't know what.

Comment: Would `brew install node` be an easier way to get a Node runtime to run your host Javascript code?  (Docker is normally designed so that a container can't edit host files, and you need to work around this core feature to use it as a development environment.)  Can you [edit] the question to include enough of your `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`, and the actual commands you're running to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I was using colima to run my docker containers on the new laptop while on the old one I was using docker desktop. I switched back and everything started working again.